# Is there a way to auto generate autokey file from key presses?

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, autokey

I am trying to copy some links from chrome to a file.
I am making these: F6, Ctrl+C, Alt+Tab, Ctrl+V, Alt+Tab, Ctrl+Tab.
I can generate a autokey file for this action but it takes some time to find the usages etc.
I am looking for a way to automate this. I mean, is there a way that listens my key presses and generates a autokey file for this?

Edit: I am not looking for automating key presses, I am trying to automate generating a autokey file, which will be used for automation.
I mean, after pressing some buttons (by me)-for example "Ctrl+C foo bar", There will be a file generated, which has

```
keyboard.send_keys("<Ctrl>+C")
keyboard.send_keys("foo bar")
```

in it, so that I can use it in autokey.
Edit: I couldn't find an answer, so I made it for myself: https://gist.github.com/sahin52/ee99bd86a78291825a5343e89a9f4c9c

Answer (score 1):

I've once did something similar- I wanted a python script to write my email address with a shortcut.
My solution was to make a script that simply writes my email then i made a shortcut to the .py file (right click- create shortcut) then in the shortcut properties i added a keystroke to calling it (properties/shortcut/shortcut key or something) works but a bit slow sometimes.

Edit: also you can use library `keyboard` (`pip install keyboard`)

```py
import keyboard, time
def press_keys():
    keyboard.send("f6, ctrl+c, alt+tab, ctrl+v, alt+tab, ctrl+tab")

keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+alt+h",lambda: press_keys())
```

Or you can make a loop-

```py
import keyboard as k

def press_keys():
    keyboard.send("f6, ctrl+c, alt+tab, ctrl+v, alt+tab, ctrl+tab")

while True:
    try:
        if k.is_pressed('ctrl') and k.is_pressed('alt') and k.is_pressed('h'):
            press_keys()
            break
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Sorry, this wasn't what I was looking for.